# NavigationBar color not changing Android 7

Tags: android, android-navigation-bar

I'm trying to change the color of the bottom navigation bar.

It supposed to be super easy using xml, I've added this lines in values/styles:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
```

**V21:**

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
```

Also tried programatically:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.navigationBarColor));
}
```

The navigation bar color won't change.  I have a viewpager with 2 fragments, each fragment has a recyclerview in it. My device running Android 7.

Any ideas?

Comment: That looks right, are you sure it's finding the color: @color/navigationBarColor?

Comment: Yes (min chars for comment)

Comment: Have you tried setting it programmatically to make sure it changes there? My only other thought is that having duplicate items are somehow interfering with each other, but that doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Programmatically way won't work also

Comment: 1. Check that your navigationBarColor is the color that you think it is. 2. check that your api version on your device is lollipop or greater